# FontAwesome.UWP icon inside a button

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm kind of noob in UWP development. I've made an app but now it's time for the stylist changes. I want to make social button in my about page (Facebook, Twitter etc). I have installed FontAwesome.UWP reference from Nuget packages.

I've inserted my Facebook Icon for example and the code goes like that:

```
<fa:FontAwesome Icon="FacebookOfficial"
                Name="facebookIcon"
                RelativePanel.Below="feedbackButton"
                Margin="10,20,0,0"
                FontSize="30"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Height="40" Width="40"/>
```

Now my problem is that I can't find how to bind this icon to the Button's content property.

Any ideas?

EDIT. I added inside the button like this:

```
<Button>
        <fa:FontAwesome Icon="FacebookOfficial"
                    Name="facebookIcon"
                    RelativePanel.Below="feedbackButton"
                    Margin="10,20,0,0"
                    FontSize="30"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Height="40" Width="40"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me: `<Button><fa:FontAwesome Icon="StackOverflow" FontSize="30"/></Button>`. Maybe try removing the `RelativePanel.Below` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontAwesome.UWP is specifically used to create GlyphIcons based on Names using FontSizes.(Atleast this is what i understand from the GitHub Documentation).

if this is true, You don't have to set up Width and Height on `FontAwesome` but play with FontSize to get your desired `Width` and `Height`.

Also Your `RelativePanel.Below="feedbackButton"` Should be set on `Button` but not `FontAwesome`.

So your final Button Code will be something like below.

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Content>
        <fa:FontAwesome Icon="FacebookOfficial"
            Name="facebookIcon"
            FontSize="30" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```